# Analyze multiple documents with one request in Azure Form Recognizer using prebuilt-invoice model

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

The DocumentAnalysisClient.StartAnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync function accepts a document URI, but we need to analyze multiple documents with a single call. How can we do that?

If there is no other way than looping through the documents and send individual request for each of them, then what is the request limit rate?

Answer (score 0):

For the request limit rate, the Azure Form Recognizer service has the following rate limits:

- Free (F0) tier: 1 transaction per second
- Standard (S0) tier: 15 transaction per second (default value)

These limits apply to the Form Recognizer service, which includes the `DocumentAnalysisClient.StartAnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync` function.

For more details please refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/service-limits.md) document.